# difference in Flex 4.5 & flex 4.5.1, air 2.5 and air 2.7

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex4.5

```
import spark.components.supportClasses.MobileTextField;
```

in my Flash Builder 4.5 there is a error: it can't find the MobileTextField class in the park.components.supportClasses. i think it is in flex4.5 sdk  and air 2.5.
so i want to know how to do it in flex4.5.1 sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a beta class and it didn't make the cut.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/MobileTextField.html

Although, you should be able to just use a TextField.  Is there some specific functionality you were needing?

Comment: hey，guys thanks， i have already find it, now in flex 4.5.1 MobileTextField must be called StyleableTextField.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the property MobileTextField as

```
MobileTextField(txtMyText.textDisplay).htmlText = "sample <b>text</b>";
```

and it works. Just needed to import:

```
import spark.components.supportClasses.MobileTextField;
```

to get it working.

Comment: it was already run in burrtio or hero(i have not tested)
now i use the Flash Builder 4.5 it can't, so i have find the new class :StyleableTextField instead of MobileTextField .